# Access violation reading location 0x00000000. 'new' keyword?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, A and Bar, both share a header file that has essentially Foo* foo in it. Class A instantiates an object Bar* bar. This works fine. However, if I make the instantiation of the object

```
Bar* bar = new Bar();
```

I get an access violation when bar attempts to do something with foo. Why does this make a difference?

If I don't use 'new' it works fine. This is the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x003c17ea in Direct3DTutorial7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading  
location 0x00000000.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the header files?

Comment: Run it in a debugger, use the callstack to find the point of the crash and add the relevant code parts.

Comment: This most likely means that you are trying to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Why `new Bar()` and not `new Bar`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

This means you're dereferencing a null pointer, likely in the constructor of `Bar`, or in some other code called by this constructor. Use a debugger to determine exactly where.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are not allocating your Foo object. As it is a global variable it is initialised to zero on program start-up, which for pointers corresponds to a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to construct a Foo object and assign it to the foo pointer?  It sounds like your Bar constructor tries to do something with foo, but you haven't created the Foo object yet.